# How to get docker volumes from newly built image?

Tags: docker

I am building a docker image with a SQLLight database using Jenkins and I believe that I want to build the database from the Dockerfile and have it stored to a volume so that I can export the volume separately. I start the build as: `docker build -t FOO .` but when I am to extract the volume data as:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from FOO -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /opt/webapp`
```

I get the error: `No such container: FOO`

This of course makes sense because FOO is not a container it's an image. But how do I get a container identifier? I can't just read whatever Docker outputs because I am batch running this in a Jenkins build.

I get the feeling I am going about this the wrong way. But what is the right way?

Comment: You want to extract the image or the data generated by a container of this image ?

Comment: I want to extract the data of the volume generated in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a container based on the `FOO` image:

```
docker run -d --name BAR FOO
```

And then you can access the volumes:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from BAR ...
```

Comment: I guess I should do `docker stop BAR` also. Seems messy to start a container and then stop it at once

Comment: Depends on the container. When there is no long running process the container is stopped immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Run the container you want to backup and do the backup directly in that container (change your entry point to something like /bin/sh if it's been modified using `--entrypoint /bin/sh`):

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/backup FOO tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /opt/webapp
```

Or, if you must run your backup in a different container (e.g. backup utilities aren't included), you only need to create the FOO container, not run it:

```
docker create --name foo-vol FOO
docker run --rm --volumes-from foo-vol -v $(pwd):/backup \
   busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /opt/webapp
docker rm -v foo-vol
```